# why Request.IsAuthenticated return true but session is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

In my ASP.NET MVC project. I use an area named **Office**.

```
Area
|--Office
     |--Controllers
           |--AccountController
                 |-- Methods: Index (authorized)

Controllers
|--HomeController
     |-- Methods: Index (not required authorized)
```

Share folder in project(*not in area*) contains: _LoginPartial.chtml, _Layout.chtml (use _LoginPartial.chtml)

This is a code in _LoginPartial.chtml:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <div class="dropdown">
        <span data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span><b>Hello</b></span>
            <span><b>@User.Identity.Name</b></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
            <li role="presentation">
                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/Office/Account/Password">Change password</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <span>.</span>
    using (Html.BeginForm("Logoff", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoffForm" })) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoffForm').submit()">Exit</a>
    }
}
else {
    <text>Log In</text>
}
```

I use the method to get session of user and if session is null, redirect to login page. Code in BaseController

```
protected Account Account
{
    get
    {
         bool flag = true;
         if (Session["User"] == null)
             flag = this.ReLogin();

         if (flag == false) return null;

         Account account = (Account)Session["User"];
         return account;             
    }
}

protected bool ReLogin()
{
    HttpCookie cookieUserName = Request.Cookies["username"];
    if (cookieUserName == null)
        return false;

    HttpCookie cookiePassword = Request.Cookies["password"];
    if (cookiePassword == null)
        return false;

    string username = cookieUserName.Value;
    string password = cookiePassword.Value;
    Account account = this.LoginWithEncrypt(username, password);
    this.SetSession(account);

    return account != null;
}

private void SetSession(Account account)
{
    if (account == null || account.IsSuspend == true)
        return;

    Session["User"] = account;

    this.SetCookie("username", account.Code);
    this.SetCookie("password", account.Password);

}

protected Account Login(string username, string password)
{
    AccountBL accountBL = new AccountBL();
    Account account = accountBL.LoadByCodeAndPassword(username, password);
    this.SetSession(account);

    return account;
}

protected void Logout()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session["User"] = null;

    this.RemoveCookie("username");
    this.RemoveCookie("password");
}
```

This is a code login in HomeController (inherited from BaseController) in Office area:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string username, string password, string returnUrl)
{
    Account account = this.Login(username, password);

    if (account == null)
    {
         ViewBag.Error = "1";
         return View();
    }
    else
    {
         FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(account.Code, true);

         if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
             return RedirectToAction("Index");
         else
             return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
}
```

I go to localhost/Home/Index, it display username. After that, I go to localhost/Office/Account/Index, it said I'm not log in so redirect me to login page.
 
**My question**: if Request.IsAuthenticated is true, but my session is null. It has something wrong and I cannot figure out.

**I try** to set FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(account.Code, true) and when log out, I remove all cookie and set FormsAuthentication.SignOut. But it doesn't work.

**My target**: if it show username, that user is have session on site.

If it doesn't clear for you, please comment below and I will edit it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you checking this in debugging mode?

Comment: @VishalVaishya: I check it in debug mode, Request.IsAuthenticated is true but session is null. :(

Comment: Check the same in Published version. It will work. Even I faced the same issue. Somehow I don't know why, sometimes in debug mode when we update do any changes in any file the session gets clear.

Comment: Consider using a membership provider, should save you a lot of time.

Comment: @Jamie: may you provide a link to custom it?