# MVC force logout if Session object is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, razor

I've been looking around and i can't find exactly what i want, or maybe it's more complex than i thought, that's why i'm asking.

Just like i see in my the _LoginPartial.cshtml :

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
        @try
        {
            <li>
                <a>@Html.Label("Hello " + Session["username"].ToString() + " !")</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Disconnect</a></li>

        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {

        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Connect", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
        }
}
else
{
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Connect", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
}
```

Sometimes, MVC calculates that `@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)` is true while in reality, my Session is completly empty.

Is there a way to link MVC Authentication with Session object or at least, force the logout if `session["username"]` is empty ?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209961/why-request-isauthenticated-return-true-but-session-is-null

Comment: So i could completly ignore the resquest.Authentication and use only the session object for my needs

Comment: Session has nothing to do with authentication - Request.IsAuthenticated merely looks to see if the current thread has a Principle object. How are you authenticating your users?

Comment: Thanks @TiesonT. just what you said answered my question, Request.Authentication has nothing to do with a real Authentication like i thought ; it's more like "the main tread exist". So i am going to use Session  instead so this way i can handle display and security myself. If you care about having an answer accepted, answer something like in your comments, Thanks everyone.

Comment: "...nothing to do with a real Authentication" - um, what? Session is just an in-memory place to store state (unless you're using Redis). What do you qualify as "a real authentication"?

Comment: When the time is out, the time is out, why do `Request.IsAuthenticated` is still true, i can't have an empty session with a main thread still running, it ruins everything, that's why at first i wanted a logOff is session["user"] is null

Comment: @TiesonT. what do you think ? i know it's not very clean but i really need persistent infos to be constently available in the pages, if these infos are not availables the person needs to relogin, as simple as that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know why i could not think of it earlyer :

```
@if (Session["username"] != null)
{
    <li>
            <a>@Html.Label("Hello " + Session["username"].ToString() + " !")</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Disconnect</a></li>
}
else
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Connect", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
}
```

Just remove the `Request.IsAuthenticated` and use directly the session object, if it is empty, you don't want a ghost user (empty session user) to be able to go around the site.